# Django internal API Client/Server Authentication or not?

Tags: python, django, api, rest, oauth

I have a django project, in which i expose a few api endpoints (api endpoint = answers to get/post, returns json response, correct me if im wrong in my definition). Those endpoints are used by me on front end, like update counts or get updated content, or a myriad other things. I handle the representation logic on server side, in templates, and in some cases send a rendered to string template to the client.

So here are the questions im trying to answer:

1. Do i need to have some kind of authentication between the clients and the server?
2. Is django cross origin protection enough?
3. Where, in this picture, fit such packages like [django-oauth-toolkit](https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit)? And [django-rest-framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/)?
4. if i don't add any authentication between clients and server, am i leaving my server open for attacks?

Furthermore, what goes for server-to-server connection? Both servers under my control.

Comment: If you are asking - should i implement oauth/openid/something authentication to protect my server from GET requests, then i would say no.

Yes the server will be open, but if none of the views allow making any changes to any objects and you have followed the django deploying guidelines (http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter12.html), then everything should be fine.

Comment: @OdifYltsaeb yeah, thats what i am wondering, should i implement oauth or such for clients. What about post calls? is csrf enough? And what about server to server?

Comment: Well i try to protect each and every one of my views as much as they require. Meaning that i have login required protected most of views and API views usually require API key. So as long as you have API key - you can do whatever the views allow:P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly recommend using [django-tastypie](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie) for server to client communication.
I have used it in numerous applications both server to server or server to client.
This allows you to apply the django security as well as some more logic regarding the authorization process.
It offers also out of the box:

- throttling
- serialization in json, xml, and other formats
- authentication (basic, apikey, customized and other)
- validation
- authorization
- pagination
- caching

So, as an overall overview i would suggest on building on such a framework that would make your internal api more interoperable for future extensions and more secure.

To specifically now answer your question, i would never enable any server api without at least some basic authentication/authorization.

Hopefully i answer your questions on how you can deliver all of your above worries with a framework.

The django-rest-framework that you ask for, is also really advanced and easy to use, but i prefer tastypie for the reasons i explain.

I hope i helped a bit!

Comment: thank you, this is indeed addresses my questions. time to go re-model my api's in a proper way. i still wonder how do you pass api key to clients w.o exposing it? and does authentication/authorization of clients slows down the page?

Comment: the authentication/authorization does not affect the response (regarding you are using a standard workflow).
i do not get exactly what you mean here " i still wonder how do you pass api key to clients w.o exposing it".
i would be glad to help, so help me understand deeper your question. Thank you very much!