# django SAAS client authentication

Tags: django, tastypie, django-rest-framework, authentication

I am designing a SAAS, multi-tenant project in Django 1.6.  This project will have separate schemas (PostgreSQL) or database per client, due to confidential data.

My question is specific on how to authenticate the user logging in and making sure it does belong to the expected customer.  Basically, what I want to avoid is that user/employee A from Customer A, being upset or wanting to make some trouble, gives user/employee B from Company B (which is a competitor) and now employee B logs in and is able to see Company A's data, which it should never happen.

After reading several posts, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20629195/django-internal-api-client-server-authentication-or-not) discusses using django-rest-framework & tastypie as options.

Before I dive into their documentation and evaluate them, are those very good options to accomplish my goal?  If there are other alternatives, please provide them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [django-tenant-schemas](http://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) may do the job for you.

The package automatically creates schemas with your tenants (Customer A, Customer B, ...) names and each tenant's schema has its own `auth_user` table (because `django.contrib.auth` is listed in `TENANT_APPS`). Therefore employee B cannot log in on Customer's A site (typically customerA.yoursite.com) and see their data (unless, of course, in the unlikely event that employee A and B have the same username/password).